# How to restore the last on demand snapshot taken via api?

Tags: mongodb-atlas

I took the backup of the database using below command

```
      CODE=`curl --user "${{ secrets.PUBLIC_KEY }}:${{ secrets.PRIVATE_KEY }}" \
          --digest --include \
          --header "Accept: application/json" \
          --header "Content-Type: application/json" \
          --request POST "https://cloud.mongodb.com/api/atlas/v1.0/groups/${{ secrets.PROJECT_ID }}/clusters/cluster-1/backup/snapshots?pretty=true" \
          --data '{ "description" : "On Demand Snapshot", "retentionInDays" : 3 }'`
```

Now I am looking for a way to use the above snapshot the restore back the database using the curl command

Answer (score 0):

First you need to get the snapshot ID of the last snapshot like this:

```
echo "Get the snapshots list from ${ATLAS_SOURCE_CLUSTER}"
curl --user "${ATLAS_USER}:${ATLAS_KEY}" \
     --output atlas-list-snaps.json \
     --digest \
     --silent \
     --header "Accept: application/json" \
     --header "Content-Type: application/json" \
     --request GET "https://cloud.mongodb.com/api/atlas/v1.0/groups/${ATLAS_SOURCE_GROUPID}/clusters/${ATLAS_SOURCE_CLUSTER}/backup/snapshots/shardedClusters?pretty=true"

#cat atlas-list-snaps.json

echo "Get the last snapshot from the list"
LAST_SNAPSHOT_ID=$(cat atlas-list-snaps.json | jq -r '.results[0].id')
echo "> ${LAST_SNAPSHOT_ID}"
```

Then, create a json payload describing your import job and then trigger the restore job:

```
echo "Restore job payload generation"
RESTORE_JOB_PAYLOAD=$(cat <<RESTORE_JOB_JSON
{
  "deliveryType": "automated",
  "snapshotId": "${LAST_SNAPSHOT_ID}",
  "targetClusterName": "${ATLAS_TARGET_CLUSTER}",
  "targetGroupId": "${ATLAS_TARGET_GROUPID}"
}
RESTORE_JOB_JSON
)
echo "${RESTORE_JOB_PAYLOAD}"

echo "Submitting restore job request to cluster ${TARGET_ATLAS_CLUSTER}"

curl --user "${ATLAS_USER}:${ATLAS_KEY}" \
     --digest \
     --header "Accept: application/json" \
     --silent \
     --header "Content-Type: application/json" \
     --output atlas-restore_job.json \
     --request POST "https://cloud.mongodb.com/api/atlas/v1.0/groups/${ATLAS_SOURCE_GROUPID}/clusters/${ATLAS_SOURCE_CLUSTER}/backup/restoreJobs?pretty=true" \
     --data "${RESTORE_JOB_PAYLOAD}"

echo "Submitted restore job"
```